# IdentityServer4 with MySql and Dot Net Core - No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.Int16' and 'System.Boolean'

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on the IdentityServer4 with MySQL and .NET Core.

When I generate the token using the [link](http://localhost/connect/token), I get the below attached error.

I converted all the Boolean fields to short.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
    .Property(r => r.IsDeleted)
    .HasConversion(new BoolToZeroOneConverter<short>());
```

[image]

Comment: Is the `IsDeleted` property a boolean?

Comment: Yes, its just an one of the table column. I convert all the Boolean fields to short. But error occurred when generate the token using connect/token.

Comment: @NithyananthamMylsamy can you share dbscript of mysql db of identity server

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're encountering a known bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92987

On the similar issue https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93028, people have reported success by switching away from `MySql.Data.EntityFramework` to `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` (an alternative OSS EF.Core implementation for MySQL). Otherwise, you may just have to wait for Oracle to fix the issue.